# How to get textLabel of selected rows and save to firebase in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, select

I am trying to get the value of the textLabel of the rows I select and save to Firebase. I want when I select multiple rows at once, to store to Firebase Database.
Here is my code.

p.s. I'm new to Swift.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return guestList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestListCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestListToTableTableViewCell
        let guest: GuestModel
        guest = guestList[indexPath.row]
        cell.fullNameLabel.text = guest.guestName! + " " + guest.guestFamilyName!
        cell.checkedImageView.image = UIImage(named: "unChecked")
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        indexArray.append(indexPath.row)
     
        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? GuestListToTableTableViewCell else { return }
            let name: GuestModel
            name =  guestList[indexPath.row]
            print("\(String(describing: name.guestName))") }
```

Here is my guest Model

```
class GuestModel {
    
    var guestName: String?
init(guestName: String?)
self.guestName = guestName }
```

Comment: You would get any data from the tableView dataSource - in the same way your tableView gets it's data. Once you click 'Save' or whatever the user does to save the data, get the selected rows indexes from the tableView, then read matching objects (via the indexes) from the dataSource `guest = guestList[indexPath.row]` and save the data to Firebase.

Comment: @Jay thank you, but I am stuck with this problem and I really do not know how to solve it, so if it is not a problem, explain it to me in an example.

Comment: My comment is the answer. Get the data you want to save from the tableView dataSource which you named `guestList`